# Only Calculate if fields meet criteria on on Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I'm trying the calculate the days between two dates on a pivot table in Excel. I have it working correctly for the most part, yet I am having an issue with the formula trying to calculate even if one of the fields is blank. Preferably, I would want the days between to only calculate if there is a date entered in both cells, since if there is only one entered it gives me an incredibly high number.

I figured I could use something like

```
=IF( OR (NOT (ISBLANK('App Received Date')), NOT(ISBLANK('Quote Date'))),SUM(ABS('App Received Date'- 'Quote Date'),0)
```

But I cant seem to get it to work correctly. I must be missing something simple but I cant get a handle on it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you step through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool? Can you see whether the conditions evaluate to what you expect?

Comment: I currently can not get to that point. I get an error message saying that "There's a problem with this formula"

Comment: Funny thing is if I use this formula outside a pivot table, while referencing cell directly, it appears to work. like instead of 'App Received Date' I use A:A

Comment: Check opening and closing braces.

Comment: Yeah its not working. Its still not ignoring entries

Comment: How/where do you apply this formula "in a pivot table"? That does not make sense.

Comment: using a calculated field?

Comment: Then please mention that in your question. Why don't you do that calculation in the data source?